# Cannot read property '_id' of null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

I get this error:

> TypeError:
>   /home/application/projetnode/projetnode/views/problemes/edit.ejs:5
>       3|         Edit Problem
>       4|
>
> > > 5|             /problemes/<%=probleme._id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST">
> > >           6|                 
> > >           7|
> > >           8|
>
> Cannot read property '_id' of null

**VIEW probleme ejs**

```
<% include ../partials/header %>
    <div class="row">
        <h1 style="text-align: center">Edit Problem</h1>
        <div style="width: 30%; margin: 25px auto;">
            <form action="/projets/<%= projet_id %>/problemes/<%=probleme._id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-block">Submit!</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
<% include ../partials/footer %>
```

**edit route**

```
  router.get("/:problemeId/edit", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
        // find probleme by id
        Projet.findById(req.params.problemeId, function(err, probleme){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                 res.render("problemes/edit", {projet_id: req.params.id, probleme: probleme});
            }
        })
    });

// route put

router.put("/:problemeId", function(req, res){
   Probleme.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.problemeId, req.body.probleme, function(err, probleme){
       if(err){
          console.log(err);
           res.render("edit");
       } else {
           res.redirect("/projets/" + req.params.id);
       }
   }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
router.get("/:problemeId/edit", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
        // find probleme by id
        Projet.findById(req.params.problemeId, function(err, probleme){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                 res.render("problemes/edit", {projet_id: req.params.problemeId, probleme: probleme});
            }
        })
    });
```

You are tring to get `projet_id: req.params.id` in your edit route but in your get route you have decleared as `router.put("/:problemeId", function(req, res)` so you have change `req.params.id` to `req.params.problemeId`

Answer (score 0):

From the error message:

```
Cannot read property '_id' of null
```

it appears that `probleme == null` in `probleme._id`. Either use `problemeId` or set the object `probleme` to non-null.